# BasicDBList to Collection MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

This may seem like a dumb question but I don't know how to do this.

I have a document in a `DBCollection` that looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("4ef4ee517e696a48037861c8"), 
    "income" : 2500, 
    "month" : "2011-12", 
    "expenses" : [    
                     {       
                         "id" : 1,       
                         "category" : "EMERGENCY",
                         "type" : "SAVING",      
                         "date" : "2011-12-23 10:25:30", 
                         "value" : 0.25" 
                     } ] 
}
```

I want to get all the elements of the inner array and put them into a `Collection` (Java `Collection`, e.g `List<E>`), but I can't seem to find anything on how to do it (and I've searched).

Comment: And what exactly did you search for? That's pretty basic stuff.

Comment: I've searched for: "convert BasicBDList to List in java" and the like, but nothing pops up...

Comment: I think one `"` fell off `date` and landed on `value`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is already a java.util.List (BasicDBList implements java.util.List)

http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBList.html

Comment: Is it safe to case `BasicDBList` to, for example, `List<String>` ?

Comment: @vikingsteve No it's not. First of all, Java can't tell, if the BasicDBList actually holds String instances, so it cannot ensure it with generics. I used it with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` like this, when I was perfectly sure that it was safe to do it: `List<String> someList = (List<String>) (List<?>) (BasicDBList) sourceList` That is probably the shortest way to get it from BasicDBList